# Silverlight UI changes freezes the application

Tags: .net, multithreading, silverlight

I have a SL application, and I have some events that once the user clicks, the app is doing some work.
This work freezes the UI until the job is done (the job modifies the UI elements).
How can I improve the performance of UI job in the SL app? I read that the UI thread is the only option.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a BackgroundWorker to do your intensive work.

[BackgroundWorker on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28VS.95%29.aspx)

It's got an event (RunWorkerCompleted) that's executed on the main/UI thread after the work is completed.

Edit:

If your background job needs to update UI, you can use the Dispatcher:

[Dispatcher.BeginInvoke on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx)

Example:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("This is executed on UI thread"));
```

Comment: most of the work is modifying the UI elements. so putting them in BackgroundWorker is not a solution